# Add blank page after each instance of new environment

Tags: environments, blank-page

**Problem:**

I am using two instances of the same environment and would like that the environment adds a blank page after each instance. Currently, it only does that for the last environment.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{book}

\newenvironment{dedication}
{
  \vspace*{5em}
  \begin{flushright}
} {
  \end{flushright}
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \phantom{.}
  \let\cleardoublepage\relax    
}

\begin{document}

% Dedictation ---------------------------------------------------

% A

\begin{dedication}
    \fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont
    \textit{To X and Y}\par
\end{dedication}

% B

\begin{dedication}
    \fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont
    \textit{To X and Y}\par
\end{dedication}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

The first dedication does not get a blank page, but the second does.

**Desired output:**

A blank page should be inserted after each dedication.

Comment: You need to put an extra `\newpage` after the `\relax` to end the empty page.

Comment: @kexxcream: Should the `dedication` itself also be on a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\newenvironment{dedication}
{
  \vspace*{5em}
  \begin{flushright}
} {
  \end{flushright}
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \phantom{.}
  \newpage %<----------------------
}

\begin{document}

% Dedictation ---------------------------------------------------

% A

\begin{dedication}
    \fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont
    \textit{To X and Y}\par
\end{dedication}

% B

\begin{dedication}
    \fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont
    \textit{To X and Y}\par
\end{dedication}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```